# Why two method with same name is not possible in Android AIDL interface

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating an AIDL interface for Remote Service Binding. In AIDL interface I am trying to create 2 methods with same name but different argume. Then compiler giving error "Attempt to redefine method". I want to know why is so,

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces do not support function overloading.

You can always add new methods to the AIDL interface.

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind that? Because after compilation .aidl convert to .java , and java support function overloading, so why not aidl.